# Asp.net Web Forms don't redirect specified Subfolder firing 404

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a legacy ASP.NET Web Forms project where has changed authentication to owin integrated authentication (before was forms authentication) . However, for a specified name subfolder (Hierarchy) redirect wont works. If I change subfolder name, for instance, to Hierarchy2, redirect works.

I my web.config has only

```
  <system.web>  
    <authentication mode="None" />
  </system.web>
```

And neither `<location>`, `<authorization>` or `<role>` tags.

I tried find all use specified name references in project, but dont found. Does anyone know what ishappenning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't found any solution, so I recreated the project.  An observation is that event application_start from Global.asax was fired twice, what was weird. But I don't time to investigate.